# Cannot POST to Express router (404 error)

Tags: javascript, express, post, routes, fetch

I cannot fetch POST requests to my Express router. I have many GET requests which work fine, but this is my first POST request and it is not working.

My frontend code looks like this:

```
export async function postHamster(name, age) {
try {
    await fetch('/hamsters/api/new-hamster',
        {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: name,
                age: age
            })
        })
    console.log("postHamster has run") //LOGGED
}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```

}

The response will always be:

```
fetchData.js:38 POST http://localhost:3000/hamsters/api/new-hamster 404 (Not Found)
```

I have triple-checked the path and it cannot be in error. The backend path is "router.get('api/new-hamster', async (req, res)..." in the file 'hamsters.js'.

I have also put the backend function at the very top of its file, to ensure that it is not overrruled by any other function in the file.

This is my server.js:

```js
    // THIS FIRST FUNCTION I JUST COPIED FROM A SOLUTION BUT IT DOES NOT SEEM TO HELP
// routes/index.js
module.exports = (express) => {
  // Create express Router
  var router = express.Router();

  // add routes
  server.route('/hamsters/api/new-hamster')
    .post((req, res) => {
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       res.send('You sent: sdadad to Express');
    });

  return router;
}

const express = require('express');
const server = express();
const serverPort = process.env.PORT || 1234;

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../build'))

let data = require('./data.json')
const { Router } = require('express');
let router = new Router();

//USE BODY-PARSER BEFORE REGISTERING ROUTES!
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
server.use(bodyParser.json())

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });

// ROUTES
const hamstersRoute = require('./routes/hamsters');
const chartsRoute = require('./routes/charts')
const gamesRoute = require('./routes/games')
const statsRoute = require('./routes/stats')
const imagesRoute = require('./routes/images')
const uploadRoute = require('./routes/upload')
    

server.use('/assets', express.static("assets"))
server.use(express.static('public'))

server.use('/hamsters', hamstersRoute)
server.use('/charts', chartsRoute)
server.use('/games', gamesRoute)
server.use('/stats', statsRoute)
server.use('/images', imagesRoute)
server.use('/upload', uploadRoute)

server.listen(serverPort, () => {
    console.log(`Server is up n running on port ${serverPort}!`)
})

module.exports = data;
```

I have looked at these threads:

[Cannot GET/POST with express Router()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38508238/cannot-get-post-with-express-router)
[Express.js routers post request returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47911884/express-js-routers-post-request-returns-404)
[Express: router cannot read POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435374/express-router-cannot-read-post-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the url you're trying to post to in the network tab in the console? I think you need to add a / before api in the backend route: router.get('/api/new-hamster', async (req, res)...".

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Instead of this:

```
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```